# How to create a static library with CMake and link it with a Haskell Stack project

Tags: c++, c, haskell, cmake, haskell-stack

I want to use a third party C++ library in my Haskell project. However, I get the following error while running `stack build`:

```
/home/ryselis/IdeaProjects/realsense-haskell/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/libHSrealsense-haskell-0.1.0.0-AnzRMqdjClnDgHnOUGe4TP.a(Realsense.o):ghc_16.c:function inline_c_Realsense_6: error: undefined reference to 'autoConfigurePersonTracking'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package realsense-haskell-0.1.0.0 using:
  /home/ryselis/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build lib:realsense-haskell exe:realsense-haskell-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The third-party library I'm using is `librealsense`. As Haskell integration with C++ is hard, I have decided to make C wrapper for this library. As a minimal example, I have tried this: I have created a CMake project. Header file excluding compiler directives looks like this:

```
extern "C" {
    void autoConfigurePersonTracking();
};
```

.cpp file contains includes to `librealsense` and defines the function `autoConfigurePersonTracking`.

In my Haskell project my stack `package.yaml` contains this section:

```
executables:
  realsense-haskell-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - realsense-haskell
    extra-include-dirs:
    - /home/ryselis/CLionProjects/realsense_c_wrapper/
    extra-lib-dirs:
    - /usr/local/lib/
    - /home/ryselis/CLionProjects/realsense_c_wrapper/
    extra-libraries:
    - realsense
    - realsense_c_wrapper
```

`realsense_c_wrapper` is the name of my static C wrapper. In my Haskell code I use `inline-c-cpp` library and have this function defined:

```
autoConfigurePersonTracking :: IO ()
autoConfigurePersonTracking = [C.block| void {
  autoConfigurePersonTracking();
}|]
```

However, linked fails with the exception given above.

My static library's header is located at `/home/ryselis/CLionProjects/realsense_c_wrapper/` and library itself is at `/usr/local/lib/librealsense_c_wrapper.a`. `librealsense` is located in the same directory and links just fine.

What am I missing?